# The discord bot does not respond

Tags: node.js

`I wrote the code, but the boy does not respond to commands at all

everything seems to be correct, and the bot is running, but the result is zero, what could be wrong? And why is this happening`

> ```
> const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');
> const client = new Client({ intents: [IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildVoiceStates, IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages, IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds] });
> const prefix = '.'; 
>
> const commands = {
>   stats: 'Show online members count',
>   help: 'Show available commands',
> };
>
> client.on('ready', () => {
>   console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
> });
>
> client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
>   const guild = newState.guild;
>   const voiceChannel = newState.channel;
>   const member = guild.member(newState.id);
>
>   if (voiceChannel) {
>     
>   } else {
>     
>   }
>
>   updateServerBanner(guild); 
> });
>
> function updateServerBanner(guild) {
>   const bannerText = `Online: ${getActiveMembersCount(guild)}\nTotal Members: ${guild.memberCount}`;
>   
> }
>
> function getActiveMembersCount(guild) {
>   let count = 0;
>   guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
>     if (channel.type === 'voice') {
>       count += channel.members.size;
>     }
>   });
>   return count;
> }
>
> client.on('message', (message) => {
>   if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return; 
>
>   const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/); 
>   const command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); 
>
>   if (command === 'stats') {
>     const guild = message.guild;
>     const activeMembersCount = getActiveMembersCount(guild);
>
>     message.channel.send(`Online: ${activeMembersCount}`);  
>   }
>
>   if (command === 'help') {
>     console.log('Help command received'); // Отладочное сообщение
>
>     let response = 'Available commands:\n\n';
>
>     for (const [command, description] of Object.entries(commands)) {
>       response += `${prefix}${command}: ${description}\n`;
>     }
>
>     message.channel.send(response); 
>   }
> });
>
> client.login('////my token/');
> ```

`I tried to write a bot for discord so that it transfers the statistics of voice online and boosters on the server to the discord server banner, maybe there is someone who understands this and can help?`

Comment: Which result is zero?  The `voiceStateUpdate` handler doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

- First, change the `message` event to `messageCreate`, as it is obsolete in discord.js v14.
- Next, since the `Guild` class no longer has a `member` method, change it to `guild.members.cache.get`.
- And the `type` property of the `GuildChannel` class now returns a numeric value. (Fortunately, there is an enumerated type that maps these numbers.)

Since the voiceStateUpdate handler appears to be incomplete, I can't say anything about it.
The code reflecting the changes made so far looks like this

```js
const { Client, IntentsBitField, ChannelType } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildVoiceStates, IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages, IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds] });
const prefix = '.'; 

const commands = {
  stats: 'Show online members count',
  help: 'Show available commands',
};

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  const guild = newState.guild;
  const voiceChannel = newState.channel;
  const member = guild.members.cache.get(newState.id);

  if (voiceChannel) {
    
  } else {
    
  }

  updateServerBanner(guild); 
});

function updateServerBanner(guild) {
  const bannerText = `Online: ${getActiveMembersCount(guild)}\nTotal Members: ${guild.memberCount}`;
  
}

function getActiveMembersCount(guild) {
  let count = 0;
  guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
    if (channel.type === ChannelType.GuildVoice) {
      count += channel.members.size;
    }
  });
  return count;
}

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return; 

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/); 
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); 

  if (command === 'stats') {
    const guild = message.guild;
    const activeMembersCount = getActiveMembersCount(guild);

    message.channel.send(`Online: ${activeMembersCount}`);  
  }

  if (command === 'help') {
    console.log('Help command received'); // Отладочное сообщение

    let response = 'Available commands:\n\n';

    for (const [command, description] of Object.entries(commands)) {
      response += `${prefix}${command}: ${description}\n`;
    }

    message.channel.send(response); 
  }
});

client.login('////my token/');
```

Sorry if my English looks bad because I am using a translator